FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols'
I have an ASP .Net Core website which runs fine locally but receives the following error when deployed to the IIS server.

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.PostConfigureNegotiateOptions.PostConfigure(string name, NegotiateOptions options)

I am referencing the following nuget packages:

microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.negotiate (8.0.0)
system.directoryservices.accountmanagement (8.0.0)
system.data.sqlclient (4.8.6)

The first two packages both reference version 8.0.0 of System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.
After deployment to the server I can see that my artifacts do indeed contain assembly version 8.0.0 of System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.
I am not sure why the Protocols dll cannot be found.
A very similar problem was the subject of this question which was posted last year.  In that question it was said there was a bug in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (7.0.0), but since I am using version 8.0.0 I am assuming this is not an issue anymore.
Any help would be appreciated.

It turns out my build steps were not copying the all of the directories of my project, so while the file existed at the root it did not exist where my application expected it.
